# Change value of a variable based on two conditions

Tags: r, if-statement, replace, conditional-statements

I'm looking for a way to have R:

1. check for a certain value in a column A
2. and if it finds it, then look at the corresponding value in a column B in a corresponding row
3. and change the corresponding value in a column C based on this.

   I.e. something like

> data$C[if(data$A==X) AND if(data$B==Y)]  = 1

I will try to illustrate it on an example.

```
Item Response Category
A    10
B    5
```

"If the Item is A and the Response is below 7, enter 1 into Category"

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Almost there : `data$C[data$A==X & data$B==Y] <- 1`. In particular, your example should be : `data$Category[data$Item == "A" & data$Response < 7] <- 1`

Comment: No comma because of the `$C`, we're subsetting a vector instead of a data.frame.

Comment: @BrianStamper: yep, fixed thanks ;)

Comment: BTW @digEmAll I keep seeing you answer in comments, why not write it as an answer?

Comment: Thanks! It doesn't seem to change the values though :(

Comment: Well this kind of questions are 1) likely duplicates of other on SO and 2) too "simple" to deserve a full answer (no offense for the OP which is likely new to R) because you learn how to solve these problem in the first steps of any R tutorial ;)

Comment: @PetrPalíšek: if you're referring to your specific small example, there's no row where Item = A and Response < 7

Comment: I found the error, it was on my side, unsurprisingly. Thanks for the help and take care :)